# Exception while starting java spark-streaming application

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

The application throws a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException`

**Stacktrace**

```
DAGScheduler: Failed to run runJob at ReceiverTracker.scala:275
Exception in thread "Thread-33" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 6.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 6.0 (TID 77, 172.20.7.60): java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.spark.examples.streaming.KafkaKeyDecoder.<init>(kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
        java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2810)
        java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1718)
        org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.onStart(KafkaInputDStream.scala:106)
        org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:121)
        org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:106)
        org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverLauncher$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:264)
        org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverLauncher$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:257)
        org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1121)
        org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1121)
        org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
        org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:54)
        org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:177)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Seems issue has already been fixed in spark 1.1.0 as per this [Link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2103)

Spark : 1.1.0
Kafka : 0.8.1.1

Comment: could you post the code as well?

Comment: I'm having same problem as you. First thing is to make that you have a constructor for KafkaKeyDecoder that has one parameter of type kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties. In my case, I have this constructor or if I'm using StringDecoder or DefaultDecoder I'm getting same exception. I'm running dse 4.6.2 with spark 1.1.0 and kafka 0.8.0. I guess that there is something in class path that creates the issue, but I did not found yet what ...

Answer (score 1):

In my case, as explained into the comment, by removing library conflicts I was able to properly consume data from kafka and store it to cassandra, deploying  the job into Datastax Analytics Solution. What I have found different than the open source one is that streaming_kafka jar and all scala libraries are already included into executor class path.

So I suggest the following:

1. Make sure that you are using same version of scala compiler as spark.
2. Make sure that kafka and streaming_kafka jars are compiled for same version.
3. Check if scala libraries are already included in executor classpath and not include them in your package.

I have assumed that you are building a uber jar that you try to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing Kafka jar containing the method.